# How to create a field of type "Customer" in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: database-design, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

There is a custom entity **E**. I would like to add a lookup field on **E**, a reference to a record of type **Contact** or **Account** (that is, a Customer/Party).

For example, there is such a field on the **Case** entity, "**customerid**" (of type Customer).

The alternative (which is what I would do on a 'plain' SQL database) would be to add two fields: ref_contact, ref_account.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't create lookup field to multiple entities in CRM. By default CRM has two specific multi-entity lookups: Customer and PartyList. Check [this article](http://crmentropy.blogspot.com/2010/07/default-entity-for-multi-entity-lookups.html) for details.

Comment: Don't forget the `Regarding` field of activities, either!